# Не отправляет картинку node-fetch discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Хочу сделать команду на рандомные картинки, вот написал код, в консоль ссылку на картинку отправляет, а в дискорде нет

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports = {
  name : 'neko',
  category : 'utility',
  description : 'Send neko image',
  run : async(client, message, args) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/neko', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'image': 'application/json'}
    });
    const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
message.channel.send(data)
}
}
```

Версия node-fetch@2.6.6
discord.js@13.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Надо было прописать

```js
message.channel.send(data.url)
```